# Using emacs interactive functions on gnu emacs, mac os x

Tags: macos, mac, emacs

For some reason, emacs functions which use the interactive form don't work for me on Mac OS x.  The emacs I am using is from [emacsformacosx.com](http://emacsformacosx.com/), which up until now has worked flawlessly.  An example of such a function that uses interactive (taken from [here](http://www.rattlesnake.com/intro/Interactive.html#Interactive)) is:

```
(defun multiply-by-seven (number)       ; Interactive version.
   "Multiply NUMBER by seven."
   (interactive "p")
   (message "The result is %d" (* 7 number)))
```

I run it in scratch with C-x C-e, but I'm not able to enter a number and get anything out.

Comment: How are you attempting to enter the number?  What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am a little worried by:

> I run it in scratch with `C-x C-e`

This does not run the function, it just evaluates it. To call the function you can evaluate:

```
(multiply-by-seven 10)
  => "The result is 70"
```

with `C-x C-e` or call it interactivly:

```
M-x multiply-by-seven
  => "The result is 7"
```

and call it with an argument

```
C-u M-x multiply-by-seven
  => "The result is 28"
```

or

```
C-u 7 M-x multiply-by-seven
  => "The result is 49"
```

as `(interactive "p")` uses the numeric prefix argument, [Emacs Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Using-Interactive)

Comment: +1 for "This does not run the function, it just evaluates it."

Comment: +1 Yup, I noticed this myself after digging in a bit more.  My emacs fu is very weak.  Thanks for the comprehensive answer.